# Agregar referencia dll de un proyecto a otro visual studio 2013 c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webservice, razor, visual-studio-2013

Tengo una solución con 6 proyectos.
Web mvc
Web services
Business
DAL
Entities
Infraestructura

El de infraestructura tiene agregada una dll en otras varias de System.Web.Mvc
Business usa infraestructura por lo tanto tiene​la dll como referencia.
En el web services le agrego la referencia dll business y al ejecutar me genera un error que dice que no encontró la dll System.Web.Mvc.Razor

Como hago que al agregar una dll de un proyecto me arrastre las dependencias de otros proyectos y dlls?

Comment: ¿Puedes replantear tu pregunta? La redacción es algo confusa y no queda claro cuál es la duda?

Comment: No creo que se puedan arrastrar las dependencias. Aprendería algo nuevo si alguien lo muestra. Yo hace tiempo trabajo con soluciones y varios proyectos y siempre me toca agregarlos manualmente.

Comment: solo una pregunta, ¿registró la dll?? o es propia de windows

Comment: Un proyecto de la capa de infraestructura no debería hacer referencia a un ensamblado que se usa en presentación. Aparte de lo comentado por los compañeros, creo que tu diseño de las capas no es del todo correcto. Saludos

Comment: porque necesitas una libreria de System.Web.Mvc en un proyecto de Infraestructura?

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda que las dependencias se copian al \bin del proyecto web por referencia directa, si hay un salto en medio puede que no se copien

Hay tres formas de solucionarlo:

- agregar la referencia a System.Web.Mvc en el proyecto de web service, puedes usar nuget
- agregar la referencia al proyecto de Infraestructura en el proyecto de web service, al ser una referencia directa agregara la dependencia
- crear un `Build Event` con el comando `copy` que lleve la dll al bin del proyecto web